# jQuery Object rewrite itself at the second turn of loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

I have an object with 2 rows of 4 inputs like color, size, price and quantity. I want to put it in one array or json object like: {"0":{"color":"black","size":"S","price":"10","quantity":"15"},"1":{"color":"white","size":"M","price":"10","quantity":"7"}} 
This code creates in loop a object with above-mentioned keys and assign it to main object, but at the second turn of loop it seems that it rewrites all the values of the main object. So, at last I receive main object from the objects with the same values (from  the last row).

The wrong result is:

```
{
    "0": {
        "color": "white",
        "size": "M",
        "price": "10",
        "quantity": "7"
    },
    "1": {
        "color": "white",
        "size": "M",
        "price": "10",
        "quantity": "7"
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 mt-2">
  <div class="form-row form-row-variety mb-2">
    <div class="col-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control color_obj" id="color_obj0" name="color_obj" placeholder="Color">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control size_obj" id="size_obj0" name="size_obj" placeholder="Size">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control price_obj" id="price_obj0" name="price_obj" placeholder="Price">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="int" class="form-control quantity_obj" id="quantity_obj0" name="quantity_obj" placeholder="Quantity">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row form-row-variety mb-2">
    <div class="col-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control color_obj" id="color_obj1" name="color_obj" placeholder="Color">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control size_obj" id="size_obj1" name="size_obj" placeholder="Size">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control price_obj" id="price_obj1" name="price_obj" placeholder="Price">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="int" class="form-control quantity_obj" id="quantity_obj1" name="quantity_obj" placeholder="Quantity">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $('.submit-edit').on('click', function (e) {
    var obj = {};
    var inputsColor = $(".color_obj");
    var inputsSize = $(".size_obj");
    var inputsPrice = $(".price_obj");
    var inputsQuantity = $(".quantity_obj");

    var main_obj = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputsColor.length; i++) {
      obj['color'] = $(inputsColor[i]).val();
      obj['size'] = $(inputsSize[i]).val();
      obj['price'] = $(inputsPrice[i]).val();
      obj['quantity'] = $(inputsQuantity[i]).val();
      main_obj[i] = obj;
    }
    var JsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
    //alert("JsonString = "+JsonString +"; ");
    var MainJsonString = JSON.stringify(main_obj);
    alert('MainJsonString = ' + MainJsonString);
    e.preventDefault();
  }); 
</script>
```

Please help to find the way to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the indexes of main_obj are pointing to the same place in memory, so when you override the attributes of obj it is updated in all the indexes of main_obj. To fix this you need to make a copy of the object and store it in main_obj.

You need to change the line in the for loop that has:

```
main_obj[i]=obj;
```

to this:

```
main_obj[i]=Object.assign({}, obj);
```

[Object.assign({}, obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) makes a copy of the object, which is then stored in main_obj.

Here is a working example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 mt-2">
         <h2>item 1<h2>
        <div class="form-row form-row-variety mb-2">
            <div class="col-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control color_obj" id="color_obj0" name="color_obj" placeholder="Color">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control size_obj" id="size_obj0" name="size_obj" placeholder="Size">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control price_obj" id="price_obj0" name="price_obj" placeholder="Price">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="int" class="form-control quantity_obj" id="quantity_obj0" name="quantity_obj" placeholder="Quantity">
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2>item 2<h2>
        <div class="form-row form-row-variety mb-2">
            <div class="col-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control color_obj" id="color_obj1" name="color_obj" placeholder="Color">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control size_obj" id="size_obj1" name="size_obj" placeholder="Size">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control price_obj" id="price_obj1" name="price_obj" placeholder="Price">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="int" class="form-control quantity_obj" id="quantity_obj1" name="quantity_obj" placeholder="Quantity">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <button class="submit-edit">Submit</button>
    </div>
<script>
$('.submit-edit').on('click',function (e) {
var obj={};
    var inputsColor = $(".color_obj");
    var inputsSize = $(".size_obj");
    var inputsPrice = $(".price_obj");
    var inputsQuantity = $(".quantity_obj");

    var main_obj=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputsColor.length; i++){
        obj['color'] = $(inputsColor[i]).val();
        obj['size'] = $(inputsSize[i]).val();
        obj['price'] = $(inputsPrice[i]).val();
        obj['quantity'] = $(inputsQuantity[i]).val();
        // put a copy of the object 'obj' in main_obj array
        main_obj[i]=Object.assign({}, obj);
    }
    var JsonString=JSON.stringify(obj);
    //alert("JsonString = "+JsonString +"; ");
    var MainJsonString=JSON.stringify(main_obj);
    console.log('MainJsonString = '+MainJsonString);  
    e.preventDefault();     
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now everything works perfect!  You solved my problem! Good luck for you!